# Remove Decoration of single window in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, window-manager, mutter

How can decoration for a single window be removed using a bash or third party program in gnome 3?

Comment: only this worked for me https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421805/30352

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try to use _MOTIF_WM_HINTS...

To remove decorations:
`xprop -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0"`

To add decorations:
`xprop -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0"`

`xprop` will then ask you to select window or if you know window `id` then you can also pass `-id` parameter to xprop. Only you can not use mouse to resize windows, but keybindings should work.

Comment: great, didn't you find an extension to do this from GUI? I miss that fine control level provided by old gnome and unity

Comment: wow, it is you! xprop didnt work here, but this worked great https://gist.github.com/muktupavels/d03bb14ea6042b779df89b4c87df975d , here is 16.04 Unity/compiz, thx! xD

Comment: I think a link to your C code could be part of your answer like here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421805/30352 :)

Comment: @AquariusPower This answer is older than my code and links can become obsolete... `xprop` should now work with compiz, at least it was supposed to be [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1702297).

Comment: Works with Cinnamon on Linux Mint 19 too

Comment: Is there a way to do this when launching the program?